# Hacer que un npc rote de acuerdo a la dirección en la que vaya en unity2D

Tags: unity3d

Necesito que un objeto en 2d que sigue una ruta y en base a esta tome una rotación acorde a dirección a la que se dirija, no estoy usando las físicas de unity2D para mover dicho objeto, esta siendo arrastrado por otro componente externo por lo que las fuerza que puede calcular unity2D las desprecia sus valores, por esto uso  métodos como invertir la dirección a un objeto enganchándolo a otro objeto para crear el efecto de rotación como si de un péndulo se tratase, pero para mantenerlo es engorroso.

¿Existe alguna método para rotar el objeto de forma que este tome la rotación dependiendo de una ruta que tome din utilizar las físicas de unity ?

Answer (score 0):

Si cada vez que el objeto avanza (en el update) guardas la posición anterior, puedes comparar la posición actual con la anterior. Con esto, por trigonometría, puedes calcular el ángulo del vector ("la línea") entre esos dos puntos con respecto al eje X o Y. Le aplicas una rotación con ese ángulo al objeto y así girará en la dirección del movimiento.

Bueno, de verdad vas a tener que agregar una cosa más, que es que dependiendo de hacia qué dirección te estés moviendo (abajo y derecha, abajo e izquierda, etc) hay que sumarle o restarle 90 grados al ángulo que habías calculado. Empieza por lo que te digo en el primer párrafo y cuando lo veas funcionar vas a entender lo que digo en el segundo.

Si necesitas más detalle, pregúntame en un comentario.

¡Suerte!

Comment: ¿Pudiste hacerlo? ¿Te sirvió mi respuesta?